# How to use dot notation while accessing an element in a multi dimension array as a parameter passed in a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

*I have been working on a multi-dimensional array.Upon working on it I have seen that if the element I want to get is a parameter in a function,then the element is inaccessible while using dot notation.*
Can some One explain why this code does so and is there any other way I can use dot notation?
**I know I can use brackets but I want to know why can't I use dot notation or there is a way?**

**Code**

```js
   _onSelect(option){
   this.componentDidMount(option.value);
    }

    componentDidMount(just){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/data/numData')
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) =>{
            var temp=(Object.keys(data.data[0]));
            var temp2=data.data;
            var temp3=[];
            if(just===undefined){
                console.error(`Variable is Undefined ${just}`);
            }else{
                for (let index = 0; index < temp2.length; index++) {
                    var justParam=just;
                    var demo=temp2[index]
                    console.log(demo.justParam)    //here justParam or just is inaccessible 

                    //temp3.push(temp2[index][`${justParam}`]);
                }
            }
            this.setState({
                x : data.time,
                y : temp3,
                selectionParam : temp
            });
        });
    }
```

**Sample response from server**

```
{"data":[
{"temperature":15,"humidity":16,"pressure":"1","rain":97,"wind":97},
{"temperature":70,"humidity":71,"pressure":"1","rain":86,"wind":86},
{"temperature":16,"humidity":17,"pressure":"1","rain":57,"wind":57},
{"temperature":37,"humidity":38,"pressure":"1","rain":38,"wind":38},
{"temperature":18,"humidity":19,"pressure":"1","rain":57,"wind":57},
{"temperature":31,"humidity":32,"pressure":"1","rain":51,"wind":51},
{"temperature":95,"humidity":96,"pressure":"1","rain":58,"wind":58},
{"temperature":49,"humidity":50,"pressure":"1","rain":9,"wind":9}
]}
```

Error

```
 Line 33:  'justParam' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
```

Here justParam is inaccessible in `temp3.push(temp2[index].justParam);`

Comment: you define `var justParam=just;` but then you never use justParam. You use `demo.justParam`, but that's not justParam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can use brackets but I want to know why can't I use dot notation or there is a way?

Square brackets take an *expression* that is evaluated as a string (or symbol) to get the property name.

Dot notation takes an *identifier* that *is* the name.

That's just how the language is designed.

It **can't** be designed so that `someObject.bar` **sometimes** means "A property named bar" and **sometimes** means "A property named after the value of the variable bar" because there is no way for JavaScript to tell the difference. It can't telepathically read the author's intent.

Answer (score -1):

```
const name = 'john'
const data = {
  name: '123',
  john: '456',

}
data.john === data['john'] === '456'
data[john] === data['name'] === '123'
```

Comment: Well, that's some code which demonstrates what the question already says and has no explanation with it at all.

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure he/she is really understanding the meaning of the code?

Comment: @BadDobby Yes I am ,but it's always better to be sure